# Testar um metodo void com mockito

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, mockito

Como testar um metodo void com mockito?

Esse é a sintax básica para um método com retorno

```
when(Classe.metodo()).thenReturn(variavelRetorno);
```

Porém, como eu faço para testar um método void?

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade o mockito não serve para testar, ele serve para criar mocks de objetos e métodos. Quando eu digo que não serve para testar, eu quero dizer que ele não vai validar se o método funcionou como esperado. Então na verdade você quer saber uma dessas duas coisas:

1. Como testar um método void.
2. Como criar um mock de um método void.

**Como testar um método void**

Se o método é void, então provavelmente a sua execução irá refletir em algum lugar de alguma forma. Algumas possibilidades:

1. Alterar o estado da classe. -> Nesse caso, para saber se o método funcionou como esperado, você irá verificar se a classe ficou no estado esperado.
2. Alterar o estado do banco. -> Da mesma forma que no item anterior, o teste deverá verificar se o banco ficou no estado esperado.
3. Geração de algum output. -> Você irá verificar se o output foi gerado e se foi gerado como esperado.
4. Integração com outro sistema. -> A integração provavelmente irá fornecer algum meio que você possa validar se o método executou como esperado. Nesse caso, a forma de testar vai depender de como a integração for feita e do que está disponível.

**Como criar um mock de um método void**

1. Usar o doAnswer.

Imaginando que você tem esse método:

```
public class App {

public void salvar(Pessoa pessoa) {
    System.out.println("Salva no banco");
}}
```

Você pode fazer isso aqui:

```
@Test
public void salvarTest() {
    App app = mock(App.class);
    Answer<Pessoa> answer = new Answer<Pessoa>() {

        @Override
        public Pessoa answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            pessoa.setId(1);

            System.out.printf("Salvando %s", pessoa.getNome());
            return null;
        }
    };

    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("João");
    doAnswer(answer).when(app).salvar(pessoa);
    app.salvar(pessoa);
    //realizar teste
}
```

O doAnswer pode ser usado quando você deseja realizar alguma operação em cima dos argumentos passados no método. Ele pode ser usado com métodos que tem retorno também. Será retornado o objeto que o answer retornar. Nesse caso, como o método é void o retorno poderia ser qualquer coisa.

2. Usar o doNothing.

-

```
App app = mock(App.class);
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("João");
doNothing().when(app).salvar(pessoa);
```

O doNohting vai fazer com que o método não faça nada quando for executado.

Answer (score 1):

Como o método é void, não é necessário configurar um retorno, logo você só precisa garantir se esse método deve ser chamado, se não deve ser chamado, ou quantas vezes ele deve ser chamado. Isso é feito através do conceito de verify, tomemos como exemplo a classe abaixo.

```
class Foo {

   public void foo() {
      //
   }

}
```

logo para verificar se o método foi chamado (uma vez):

```
Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);

verify(mockFoo).foo();
```

Se foi chamado mais que uma vez (no caso abaixo 2x):

```
verify(mockFoo, times(2)).foo();
```

Se não deve ser chamado o método void:

```
verify(mockFoo, never()).foo();
```

O ideal é sempre consultar a documentação do mockito que é muito boa em minha opinião:
http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4

Answer (score 0):

Oi!
Quando você esta usando mockito, você define como será o seu cenário.
Nesse exemplo que você citou você esta definindo o que vai acontecer.

Agora, se você quer validar se as chamadas dentro do seu método void foram executadas, você pode usar o Mockito.verify(...) por exemplo.
Veja na documentação:
http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification

Espero ter te ajudado.